# pdo_mysql installation

Tags: linux, installation, pdo

On my server I'm trying to instal PHProjekt (6). This requires pdo_mysql however. I thought this installation of pdo_mysql would be rather straightforward...

I tried using pecl (pecl install pdo_mysql) after installing devel etc, but this came up with a permission denied error. I solved this by using directories that were accessible. It then came up with a cant run C compiled programs however. It also says to check config.log for more details but ironically config.log is automatically removed if the installation process fails...
When I try to compile and output a "hello world".c however, it works perfectly.

I then tried to download the pdo_mysql stuff and install in myself (using configure and make install). This seemed to do the job, but when I restarted my apache ... no sign of pdo_mysql anywhere even though I adjusted my php.ini file

I have read somewhere that you need to recompile PHP with the option pdo_mysql enabled. But how does one do that (I'm using CentOS4). And isn't there any other way than that???

I compiled PHP 5.2.9 from source into /usr/local.

Thanks!

Comment: the original server came with PHP 4, and I upgraded it using yum

Comment: hmmm, it returns php-4.3.9-3.29 :-/ ... entering php -v however returns: 
PHP 5.2.9 (cli) (built: May 26 2009 17:49:45)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies

Comment: the 5.2.9 version ...

Comment: I did  rpm -qf /usr/bin/php which gave me the 4.3.9 version,
 but couldn't find where the 5.2.9 lives

Comment: okay, which php returned:
/usr/local/bin/php
when using this path with rpm -qf I got the following:
file /usr/local/bin/php is not owned by any package

Comment: Alright, add the fact that you compiled 5.2.9 from source into `/usr/local` to your question.

Comment: done :-) but how is this preventing me from installing pdo_mysql?

Comment: Dunno. But now people that might know are aware that you're not using the stock PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution.

I downloaded the PHP tar.gz file, 
rebuild PHP with the option '--with-pdo_mysql=shared'  added, 
manually installed pdo_mysql like this:
wget url_of_the_tar
tar xzf file_name
cd created_directory
phpize
./configure
make install clean

because I had several extensions loaded already I couldn't change the extensions_dir property in the php.ini file, but to my big surprise, moving the extensions from the ../no-debug-.../ folder to the correct folder everything worked.

I still think it's a ***load of work to install a simple extension, but hey, it worked!